# I am trying to trigger onchange function without click on it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to trigger onchange function without click on it using code I am using simple code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<script>
 $('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
 });
</script>
```

now I just need to select on of the option and need to alert there value. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Just chain a `val` and a `change` call on it:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
    console.log( this.value );
}).val('2').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

If you don't want to trigger it on page load, you can of course do this any time:

```
$('select').val('2').change();
```

Comment: Also `$('select').val('2').trigger('change')`

Comment: Yes, the [documentation on `change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change) states: *This method is a shortcut for [...] `.trigger( "change" )`.*